# Drupal 8 article twig template - inserting filed value

Tags: templates, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to insert a field value (all selected from drop-down list, machine name - field_categories) to a twig article template,

```html
{% if display_submitted %}
    <footer class="node__meta">
      {{ author_picture }}
      <div{{ author_attributes.addClass('node__submitted') }}>
        {% trans %}<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  {{ createdDate }} / <i class="fa fa-user"></i>  {{ author_name }} / <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ categories }}{% endtrans %}
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    </footer>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In which template are you trying to do stuff ? in your own `node--article--full.html.twig` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the variable after I removed {%trans%} tags to display just the first value, but how would you display multiple selected values from drop-down?

```html
{% set categories = content.field_categories.0 %}
      
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  {{ createdDate }} / <i class="fa fa-user"></i>  {{ author_name }} / <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ categories }} 
{{ metadata }}
```

Comment: instead of using `.0` you could use the `|first` filter of twig. Eg. `content.field_categories|first`. It's more elegant.